Find if the difference between today and event date is more than 10 in excel
I want to check whether the event date and today date difference is more than 10days,if so then print the days if not then print its less than 10 days in excel..
Formula:
=IF(DATEDIF(B3;TODAY();"d")>10;DATEDIF(TODAY();B3;"d");"Less than 10days")
I wanted to get , say the event date is 24th April 2024 and TODAY() it should show the days 19days but its showing an error.

I managed getting it to work as follows:
=IF(ABS(B3-TODAY())<10;"less than 10 days";ABS(B3-TODAY()))

As you see, you can simply subtract dates from each other. A day is simply counted as 1.

Give this a go:
=IF(IFERROR(-DATEDIF(A1;TODAY();"d");DATEDIF(TODAY();A1;"d"))<-10;"Less than 10days";IF(IFERROR(-DATEDIF(A1;TODAY();"d");DATEDIF(TODAY();A1;"d"))>10;"greater than 10 days";""))

